# JSON returning caret (^) in the value and returning null in the response

Tags: java, json, serialization, kibana, getter-setter

I am working on mapping json values with kibana, one element i.e amount it is returning beginning with "^" and its not mapping the getters and setters. How could I map it?, I used @jsonProperty and @jsonCreator as well but still seeing null in the value.

example:

```
{
  "value": "530b8371",
  "Code": "AH",
  "^amount": "$275,817.49",
  "description": "grant"
}
```

Comment: Did you try `@JsonProperty("^amount")`?

Comment: @yes I tried it on setter and getter methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This is not (necessarily) an answer, but is needed to show code.*

**Unable to reproduce** the issue posed in the question.

The following Jackson mapping code using `@JsonProperty` works fine.

*Imports used below*

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
```

*Option 1: Using `@JsonProperty` on fields*

```java
class Foo {
    @JsonProperty
    private String value;
    @JsonProperty("Code")
    private String code;
    @JsonProperty("^amount")
    private String amount;
    @JsonProperty
    private String description;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Foo[value=" + this.value + ", code=" + this.code +
                 ", amount=" + this.amount + ", description=" + this.description + "]";
    }
}
```

*Option 2: Using `@JsonProperty` on methods*

```java
class Foo {
    private String value;
    private String code;
    private String amount;
    private String description;

    @JsonProperty
    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Code")
    public String getCode() {
        return this.code;
    }
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    @JsonProperty("^amount")
    public String getAmount() {
        return this.amount;
    }
    public void setAmount(String amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Foo[value=" + this.value + ", code=" + this.code +
                 ", amount=" + this.amount + ", description=" + this.description + "]";
    }
}
```

*Option 3: Using `@JsonCreator` on constructor*

```java
class Foo {
    private String value;
    private String code;
    private String amount;
    private String description;

    @JsonCreator
    public Foo(@JsonProperty("value") String value,
               @JsonProperty("Code") String code,
               @JsonProperty("^amount") String amount,
               @JsonProperty("description") String description) {
        this.value = value;
        this.code = code;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Foo[value=" + this.value + ", code=" + this.code +
                 ", amount=" + this.amount + ", description=" + this.description + "]";
    }
}
```

*Test*

```java
String json = "{\r\n" + 
              "  \"value\": \"530b8371\",\r\n" + 
              "  \"Code\": \"AH\",\r\n" + 
              "  \"^amount\": \"$275,817.49\",\r\n" + 
              "  \"description\": \"grant\"\r\n" + 
              "}";
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Foo foo = objectMapper.readValue(json, Foo.class);
System.out.println(foo);
```

*Output (same for all `Foo` classes above)*

```
Foo[value=530b8371, code=AH, amount=$275,817.49, description=grant]
```